# str_replace PHP script can't handle foreign characters such as umlauts robustly

Tags: php, apache, str-replace, diacritics

The following script does not always correctly catch and convert foreign characters. Could someone show me what I'm missing to get it to be more robust?

```
<?php
include("../index_head.inc.php");
$content = implode("",(@file("current.txt")));

$url = "http://XXXXXX.html?no_body=1";
$content = file_get_contents($url,'r');

if (isset($_GET['showcurrent']) && $_GET['showcurrent'] == '')
    {
    $content = substr($content,1,strpos($content,"<hr ")-1);
    }
    else 
    {
    $content = str_replace("<br style=\"clear:both\" />\n</p>", "</p>",$content);   
    $content = str_replace("ck1\"><img", "ck1\" target=_blank><img",$content);  
    };

$content = str_replace("<h3>current</h3>", "",$content);

echo "<div id=\"service\" style=\"width: 660px;padding-left:5px\">",str_replace("current.html","current.html",$content),"</div>";

include("../index_footer.inc.php");
?>
```

New information: Pekka, you gave me the idea to check how the page emits without str_replace():

```
<?php
include("../index_head.inc.php");
$content = implode("",(@file("current.txt")));
$url = "XXXXXX.html?no_body=1";
$content = file_get_contents($url,'r');
echo "<div id=\"service\" style=\"width: 660px;padding-left:5px\">",$content,"</div>";
```

It seems the problem lies elsewhere because I get the same mangling even **without** using str_replace()! If you can help me get this sorted out, I would sure appreciate it. I have seen your wish list. ;)

Comment: That's why PHP provides the [multibyte string library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php)... str_replace, substr, etc work on bytes, not characters

Comment: @MarkBaker there's no mb_str_replace though.

Comment: Thanks Mark and Sébastien. I used your comments to find this: (
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786003/str-replace-on-multibyte-strings-dangerous)

Comment: I tried the mb_replace function described in 3786003, but it didn't change a thing. The problem remains.

Comment: I do not see any instance in your code where it tries to replace an umlaut? What exactly fails where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you include the charset in php?

try this:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

If not working check if your file is already saved in utf8 before str replace:

```
utf8_encode ( string $data );
```

In the opposite case use:

```
utf8_decode( string $data );
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It did! Thank you SBO.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you SBO - It sure did help! I simply changed the code to:

```
<?php
include("../index_head.inc.php");
$content = implode("",(@file("current.txt")));

$url = "http://XXXXXX.html?no_body=1";
$content = file_get_contents(utf8_encode($url),'r');

if (isset($_GET['showcurrent']) && $_GET['showcurrent'] == '')
    {
    $content = substr($content,1,strpos($content,"<hr ")-1);
    }
else 
{
$content = str_replace("<br style=\"clear:both\" />\n</p>", "</p>",$content);   
$content = str_replace("ck1\"><img", "ck1\" target=_blank><img",$content);  
};

$content = str_replace("<h3>current</h3>", "",$content);

echo "<div id=\"service\" style=\"width: 660px;padding-left:5px\">",str_replace("current.html","current.html",utf8_decode($content)),"</div>";

include("../index_footer.inc.php");
?>
```

and everything is working fine.
Thank you very much for your help.