# Replace a specific letter in hindi with another letter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, hindi

I m using hindi language to display data to user. but i want to replace a specific letter from all the words that appears to user. I want to replace
 
  "ख" with "ष" 
"खा" with "षा" 
and respectively. I want to replace this at the time of inserting in database.
Means if user types "ख" in any form , it should be inserted as "ष" in database. So anybody has idea about this???

Comment: I don't know hindi and language construct but you can look in to php manual and try "str_replace" function

Comment: [You may check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786003/str-replace-on-multibyte-strings-dangerous).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mb_ereg_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php)

```
<?php 
$a='[ख]';
$string="खखखख Hello खखखखखख";
$b=mb_ereg_replace( $a, 'षा' , $string );
echo $b;

//output:  षाषाषाषाषाषाषाषा Hello षाषाषाषाषाषाषाषाषाषाषाषा
?>
```

Make sure you set your html to `utf-8`
and include this at the start of your page:

```
define('CHARSET','UTF-8');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

I created my own library file called stringhandler.php. following is the stringhandler.php.

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class stringhandler {

 function normalize_str($str)
{
$invalid = array('ख'=>'ष', 'खा'=>' षा', 'खि'=>'षि', 'खी'=>'षी', 'खु'=>'षु', 'खू'=>'षू',
'खे'=>'षे', 'खै'=>'षै', 'खो'=>'षो', 'खौ'=>' षौ', 'खं'=>' षं', 'खः'=>'षः');

$str = str_replace(array_keys($invalid), array_values($invalid), $str);

return $str;
}
}
```

And in model file

```
'fname'=>$this->stringhandler->normalize_str($this->input->post('fname')),
'fathername'=>$this->stringhandler->normalize_str($this->input->post('fathername')),
```

Hope this will help someone..