# Replace char in text, read from mssql database, with another. (php)

Tags: php, html, sql-server

I read the following text out of a Mssql database:

> 19. Leitwert und Korrosionsschutz des Kühlwassers überprüfen: 111- Umrichterkühlkreis < 200µS/cm 111- Ofenkühlkreis und IGBT-Anlagen: < 400µS/cm 111- Konzentration des Korrosionsschutzes

I want to replace "111" with a new line (`"<br>"`) using this replace function:

`str_replace("111",  "<br>", $text);`

or this one

`array_replace("111",  "<br>", $text);`

Both lines work when I declare the text just in the code, but if I read it from the database it doesn't work. I use `utf8_encode` after reading this text from db.

I think the problem is the datatype which is defined as "text" in the table of the database.

Comment: Why are you using the `text` datatype in the first place? It's been deprecated since at least SQL Server 2005. You should really be using `varchar(MAX)`.

Comment: Can't you just load it all into an array then loop and format it to your liking?

Comment: This may be a [good Q&A to read through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786003/str-replace-on-multibyte-strings-dangerous)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function.

```
$string = 'Leitwert und Korrosionsschutz des Kühlwassers überprüfen: 111- Umrichterkühlkreis < 200µS/cm 111- Ofenkühlkreis und IGBT-Anlagen: < 400µS/cm 111- Konzentration des Korrosionsschutzes';

$string = preg_replace('/111/', '<br>', $string);

echo $string;
```

This will output:

```
Leitwert und Korrosionsschutz des KÃ¼hlwassers Ã¼berprÃ¼fen:
- UmrichterkÃ¼hlkreis < 200ÂµS/cm
- OfenkÃ¼hlkreis und IGBT-Anlagen: < 400ÂµS/cm
- Konzentration des Korrosionsschutzes
```

Comment: Glad it helped!  ~Cheers

Comment: Sorry but I'm unable to see why this code should be have differently than the one in the question. Isn't it the the same byte-level search and replace?

Comment: @ Álvaro González  I do not have an answer for you as I believe you are correct as to the same byte-level operations.  Either the OP changed his code to mirror the flow of my code, or did not utf8_enode the data prior to feeding it through the functions, or there is a difference between the two functions with his current set up.  I was thinking about this too.  I would also like to point out that the OP's assumption was an encoding error, when in fact it may not be.

Answer (score 0):

[utf8_encode()](http://php.net/utf8_encode) is a poorly named function that's often used having no clue of its actual purpose. If you work with SQL Server, it's very unlikely that you have ISO-8859-1 strings coming from the database because:

1. Microsoft's RDBM works natively with two encodings at the same time, a Unicode-compatible one (if `NTEXT` column type) and ANSI (if `TEXT` column type). "ANSI" is just a generic term for "Windows default codepage in the computer where the server runs" and it can be something like Windows-1252 but not ISO-8859-1.
2. PHP database extensions typically convert database strings from/to the application encoding and they do it transparently (they also do it *correctly* if you set connection settings properly).

So it's very likely that's the source of your problems.

Last but not least, [str_replace()](https://php.net/str_replace) is a legacy function that isn't multi-byte aware. Unfortunately, it doesn't have a multi-byte equivalent but you can find [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786003/str-replace-on-multibyte-strings-dangerous) out there.